# sql max date query

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my query:

```
SELECT ITM.CODE
     , Price
     , STL.DATE_ AS gun
FROM LG_094_ITEMS ITM WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN LG_094_01_STLINE STL ON ITM.LOGICALREF = STL.STOCKREF
WHERE Price > 0
    AND TRCODE = 1
    AND CANCELLED = 0
    AND INVOICEREF > 0
    AND STL.LINETYPE = 0
```

I couldn't figure our how to get the latest prices of the codes.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: We can't figure it out either unless you post your table structure and sample data....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` here:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT ITM.CODE
         , Price
         , STL.DATE_ AS gun
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ITM.CODE ORDER BY STL.DATE_ DESC) AS RN
    FROM LG_094_ITEMS ITM WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN LG_094_01_STLINE STL ON ITM.LOGICALREF = STL.STOCKREF
    WHERE Price > 0
        AND TRCODE = 1
        AND CANCELLED = 0
        AND INVOICEREF > 0
        AND STL.LINETYPE = 0
) prices
WHERE RN = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT ITM.CODE
         , Price
         , STL.DATE_ AS gun
         , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ITM.CODE ORDER BY STL.DATE_ DESC)
    FROM LG_094_ITEMS ITM
    INNER JOIN LG_094_01_STLINE STL ON ITM.LOGICALREF = STL.STOCKREF
    WHERE Price > 0
        AND TRCODE = 1
        AND CANCELLED = 0
        AND INVOICEREF > 0
        AND STL.LINETYPE = 0
) t
WHERE t.RowNum = 1
```